# hMailServer to send mail to domain users

Tags: email, mail-server, hmail-server

I have discovered an issue with our setup of hMailServer.

The server is running on a single server outside of the corporate environment, so I can't (currently at least) set it up to mail through the corporate email server.

So, in the administration settings, I have set up the domain xxx.org, which is the corporate domain, but it is set to deliver mail from the local installation.

The application that is running on that server always sends emails from the same email address, say yyy@xxx.org.

The problem occurs when I want to send an email to another user on the same domain. So I try to send an email from yyy@xxx.org to zzz@xxx.org.

hMailServer thinks it is the mail server for the whole domain, so it returns immediately saying the user is not found, which of course it wouldn't be because the only account I set up was the one for the server to send mails from: yyy.

I can't seem to find an option anywhere to get it so that mails to other addresses @xxx.org will send successfully, as they do for all other domains.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!